C# SortedSet<T> uses the custom comparer for add/remove/contains as well as sorting?
I was trying to use a SortedSet to keep a set of objects in order with a custom comparer but found that SortedSet is not working how I expected or how the documentation describes it.  When using Add(), Remove(), or Contains() the SortedSet uses the custom comparer to find the target item in the list instead of checking the items themselves.
For example if I have a SortedSet of vectors and have the custom comparer compare them by their magnitudes if I first add a vector (1, 2) and then try to add (2, 1) it will fail because the comparer says they are equal.
Is this how it should work?  The documentation only says that the comparer is used for sorting and that Add() doesn't allow duplicate elements, I feel it could really use a note about the custom comparer if that is intended.
Additionally: Is there a sorted collection that does what I am looking for?  A Key/Value pair collection that sorts on the value so there may be duplicate values.

When the documentation is lacking sometimes the best option is to read to source, for example here is the implementation of SortedSet<T>.Add
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedSet.cs#L299
Perhaps you can provide some context for the set's usage, may help provide the best type for you to use, without more inform perhaps type  List<T> with Linq OrderBy to make it sorted.

A notable difference between a set and a list is that items in a set are unique. If you give a custom comparer to a set that declares (1,2) and (2,1) to be equal then the set cannot be made to contain both. Change your comparer so that they are not considered equal and that one is reliably considered to be "less than" before the other

Is there a sorted collection that does what I am looking for? - a List<(int, int)> that you call Order() on? The default comparer for tuples will consider (1,2) to be less than (2,1)

My use case is similar to the example I gave in the question.  I am making a navigation system that has a set of nodes which it calculates a weight for and finds the lowest weight path to the goal.  So I want a collection of nodes that are sorted by their weight.  Of course I can just use a list and sort it with a function but the frequent cycle of adding, removing, and getting the lowest weight node felt more suited to a sorted list than repeatedly sorting the whole collection.


Is this how it should work?

Yes, if the comparer returns 0 it means the items are equal, and since it is a set, it will not allow multiple items that are equal.

Is there a sorted collection that does what I am looking for? A Key/Value pair collection that sorts on the value so there may be duplicate values.

That depend on what you are looking for and what you goal is. It is probably a good idea to list the operations that need to be supported, and what algorithmic complexity you need for each one. As a rule of thumb, key value collections would use the key as the index. The built in collections are intended for common usages. If you have some specialized use case you may need to create your own collection type.
There is a MultiValueDictionary that allow multiple values for a single key. Unfortunately it seem the package has been deprecated, but it is not that difficult to create your own equivalent collection.
There is a sorted dictionary, that could be extended to allow for multiple values per key. Just use a backing SortedDictionary<double,List<TValue>>, with an add method that either creates a new list or adds the value to the existing list.
If you want have spatial data you would typically use some kind of tree. R-Tree is the typical spatial index. But Kd-Tree or Quad-tree are also alternatives. There are no built in types for this in c#, but some databases have spatial indices, and there should be plenty of third party libraries if you look around.

Thanks for the response.  The documentation makes it sound, to me, that the custom Comparer object is used only for the sorting operation and that the set doesn't allow "duplicate" elements so I would expect them to use a default comparer for that object.
It looks like all the sorted collections require a unique key to sort by so I can either implement my own or just use a list and sort it.

@wabafet while you are correct that the documentation is not always as explicit as one would want, using the default equality comparer would make very little sense to me considering that IComparable has equality comparison built in. And it would make the collection much less useful for reference types if there is no way to override the default reference equality.
